# Strange output with pi calculating in Chicken Scheme

Tags: scheme, sicp, chicken-scheme

The version info: Version 4.9.0.1 (stability/4.9.0) (rev 8b3189b) macosx-unix-clang-x86-64

The code is actually for exercise 1.3.1 in SICP:

```
(define (product term a next b)
    (define (iter a result)
        (if (> a b)
            result
            (iter (next a) (* (term a) result))
        )
    )
    (iter a 1)
)

(define (get-pi n)
    (define (next x) (+ x 2))
    (define (term x) (* x x))
    (* 8 n (/ (product term 4 next n) (product term 3 next (+ n 1))))
)
```

The output:

```
#;102> (get-pi 165) 
3.13208714360219
#;103> (get-pi 167)
3.13220081034665
#;104> (get-pi 169)
3.13231179078142
#;105> (get-pi 170)
0.0
```

Why the result became 0.0?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Chicken doesn't implement the full numeric tower by default. You need to [`(use numbers)`](http://wiki.call-cc.org/friendly-chicken).

I don't have Chicken installed, but you might have to use `(exact->inexact (get-pi 170))` to get the same results as before.